# Optimize read from m-to-n relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have a classic m-to-n relationship between `app_user`, `user_post` and `user_comment`. You can take a look at the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/60d67/1) example.

```
------------     ----------------     -------------
| app_user |----<| user_comment |>----| user_post |
------------     ----------------     -------------
```

#### Task

Given a `created_at` timestamp for a user post, I want to fetch *all* `user_comment` records, if the user has created a comment on a post that was created before a certain date.

#### Solution

The following is how such a query could look like, but I was wondering if this can be optimized for speed. As you can see, there's four `SELECT` statements involved as sub-queries.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM user_post
JOIN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM user_comment
  WHERE user_comment.app_user_id IN (  
    SELECT user_comment.app_user_id
    FROM user_comment
    WHERE user_comment.user_post_id IN (
      SELECT user_post.id
      FROM user_post
      WHERE user_post.created_at < '2022-01-02 00:00.00'
    )
  )
) AS fpr ON fpr.user_post_id = user_post.id;
```

Extra points if somebody can show me how to implement an optimized version using `sqlalchemy`.

I can tell you this: ChatGPT does not seem to be able to understand this assignment.

Comment: Wondering if [prompt design guidelines](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/completion/prompt-design) might help to make ChatGPT return something helpful about this (not a slqalchemy expert to learn this by my self, please let me know if you tried it, tried for Google Apps Script having mixed results)

Comment: @Rubén I've presented ChatGPT with everything but it didn't understand that I want _all_ the posts. ChatGPT would always generate a query which gave me a user-record and one post id that matched the time-criterion. Tried different things, it wasn't able to do that.